# What is the word for situation when something was done in most probable way, despite the fact it could go differently by an accident?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: on my daily way to work I could trip and hurt my leg accidently, but if I arrive without being hurt, how should I describe it? I arrived _ _ _ ?

*Luckily or happily* are words that seem to fit above example, but what if the "happy" or "lucky" way of doing things is statistically insignificant? For example, if my daily way to work would require walking through tree districts with the highest crime rate, I could say *I accidently arrived without being hurt*, but what should I say if things went as expected? I arrived _ _ _?

Edit: Is there a word which fits both situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already used the most fit phrase. When something went the most probable way, people usually say "It went as expected"

> I went through three districts with the highest crime rate. As expected, I was assaulted and robbed. I was lucky to make it out in one piece.

There is a lot ways to say something similar to what you want. *As foreseen, as predicted, as suspected* and so on. But they are less generic - it wouldn't be sensible to go into a district if you predict you'll be assaulted there, isn't it?

Comment: haha, indeed, I used it already :) Thanks! I wouldn't notice otherwise...

Comment: Now I wonder... Is "as expected" one word?

Comment: Apparently not. It's shortened version "as it was expected" (I believe). Why?

Comment: I searched for sigle-word :) Maybe *I arrived expectedly* is correct?

Comment: You've got me confused. What is the most probable outcome in your situation? That you arrived safely, or you were assaulted?

Comment: In the first one, I should have arrived safely, in the latter, got stabbed in the back.

Answer (score 1):

I accidently arrived without being hurt, but what should I say if things went as expected? I arrived *[unscathed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unscathed)*.

The definition of the [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unscathed) reads:

> **unscathed** Not injured or harmed: *escaped the hurricane unscathed.*

This word is used when there is a significant probability that you can be hurt (in an accident or a natural catastrophe for instance).

If you want to emphasise the "*lucky*" sense (as in your second example situation) you can also add **miraculously**.

- I arrived *miraculously unscathed*!
- Also simply found as *miraculously unharmed*!

If on the contrary there is only a low risk of being harmed you can use

- the set phrase *safe and sound*.
- or just *safe*.

If you want to say that you didn't suffer the slightest injury you can use

- *unscratched*. Also used for a car (if you go through a pile up and your car is the only one that got through for instance).

Comment: Is there a word that fits both situations?